# Unable to exclude files from Sonar

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube

I am scanning Sonar using MSBuild. Currently I am unable to find a way to exclude certain files. Does anyone know how to exclude certain files?

We are using Sonar Version 5.6.1

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! I suggest you [take a tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and update your post with more details on your environment, on your issue and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

This is configured through the UI at **Administration > General Settings > Analysis Scope**. Use a valid regex to specify which files should be ignored.